# Docker not detecting changes for react app in windows

Tags: reactjs, docker

I generated a base react app with `create-react-app` and generated a `Dockerfile.dev` inside of the project directory

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

Ran the build with `docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t dawnmd/react .`

Started the docker container with `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v ${PWD}:/app dawnmd/react`

The app not detecting changes from the host i.e `windows 11` when I change something in the host file.

Comment: Yes, It is expected once build a docker image all files are containerized it's better to make all the changes in your host system first and then build the image.

Comment: Weird, are you running the `docker run` command from PowerShell? Otherwise, with Windows command line, it should be %cd%:/app instead of ${PWD}. Your approach definitely works for me, on Linux.
Does it show the correct "Mounts" entry if you run `docker container inspect <containername>` ?

Comment: @Ashis But I want to use the volume feature in docker so that I don't have to rebuild it every time.

Comment: @manuelkruisz I'm using GitBash.
`{
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "C:\\Users\\maina\\Desktop\\docker\\reactdocker;C",
                "Destination": "\\Program Files\\Git\\app",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
}`
The source here is showing `reactdocker;C` instead of `reactdocker`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true doesn't work with docker and windows 11.

However there is a workaround - you can use vscode remote container extension found here:

- VSCode Documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers
- VSCode Remote Download: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers

If you have Docker Desktop installed, VSCode installed, and VSCode Remote containers installed. You can then do the following:

1. Open the react project in VSCode
2. Press CRTL + SHIFT + P, and then *type and select* the following: "Remote-Container: Open folder in Container"

[image: VSCODE Open in Remote Containers]

3. It would then ask for, "Add Development Container Configuration Files" to which you can select one of the following from **dockerfile, docker-compose, or from predefined container configuration**. Your project maybe different from mine hence the selection is up to you.

[image: VS Code Remote-Container Configuration]

4.Once Everything has been loaded. Using VSCode select terminal from the menu and then **new terminal** and then type "npm start" or "yarn start" as shown on the figure.

[image: Running React in Remote-Container]

*Opinion: The benefit of running react using vscode remote container is that the computer doesn't have to work much harder as it re-compiles/rebuild react whenever you save the js file on demand. Unlike chokidar_usepolling which compiles react every-second. Which makes my computer scream running a virtual library and the constant reload on the browser.

Note: Any changes made in the remote-container is also saved in the host machine.
Note: You would have to use git bash or another terminal(i.e Powershell) to execute all git commands as the terminal in vscode opens a terminal which resides in the container.

Answer (score 1):

For windows using power-shell the run command will be:

`docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3000:3000 -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true <IMAGE>`

`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` enables a polling mechanism via chokidar (which wraps fs.watch, fs.watchFile, and fsevents) so that hot-reloading will work