# Docker not detect changes with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am running Docker on Windows 11.
I have four services:

- NestJS (Backend)
- ReactJS (Frontend)
- Postgres (DB)
- PGAdmin (DB Manager)

My backend detect changes correctly, but my frontend not detect changes.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: fortunesp_nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    networks:
      - shared-network

  app-prod:
    container_name: fortunesp_frontend
    image: fortunesp_frontend:1.0.0
    build:
      context: client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - api-prod
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - shared-network
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./client:/usr/src/app

  api-prod:
    container_name: fortunesp_backend
    image: fortunesp_backend:1.0.0
    build:
      context: server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/postgres/5432; do sleep 1; done; npm run start:dev'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: "true"
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - shared-network
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "http://api-prod:9000"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 15s
      retries: 6
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/api
      - /usr/src/api/node_modules/bcrypt/

  pgadmin:
    container_name: fortunesp_pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=root@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - shared-network

  postgres:
    container_name: fortunesp_postgres
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=fortunesp
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U $$POSTGRES_USER $$POSTGRES_DB" ]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - shared-network

networks:
  shared-network:

volumes:
  postgres: {}
```

Dockerfile (client)

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

ENV NODE_PATH=/node_modules
ENV PATH=$PATH:/node_modules/.bin

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I can't find the problem.
Another thing I tried was to verify that in docker my file is being modified, and its correct, my file is modified successfully.
The problem is that my console does not compile again when I modify my files.

I am using react app create.
Docker Desktop 4.6.0.
Windows 11 Pro.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *does not detect changes*? Have you tried to use `docker build` with the `--no-cache` flag?

Comment: but you don't do any build for your frontend, you just copy the files. Usually you should copy files and build them then inside the docker container

Comment: @Mushroomator Oh, I run my Frontend from Dockerfile with "npm start" and I working with my Frontend, so I modify any file then my frontend should refresh my changes, but not are detected.
Also I tried with --no-cache, but not working for me.

Comment: @Georgy I mounted the volume: 
- ./client:/usr/src/app
in my docker-compose.yml to link files, and I run "npm start" from my Dockerfile to wait for changes in realtime.

Comment: hmm, I see you use `WORKDIR /usr/app` and you copy all files there, but you mount  your host `client` folder to `/usr/src/app`. And this is not the workdir folder. You should check that dev server inside the container serve the files you are actually changing in your host machine

Comment: @Georgy Oh thank you, I was modifying the files and I think I forgot to fix it. 
I changed to `usr/src/app` but I get same result.

Comment: You can check the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759267/docker-not-detecting-changes-for-react-app-in-windows